# Bootstrap tabs have no tab frame border

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins, tabs

I've tried setting up the code for using the Twitter Bootstrap Tabs plugin a number of different ways, however the tab frame border never shows up in my browser. Yet, in the Bootstrap tutorial example it works fine. Does anyone know what could be the problem?

I don't have enough reputation, otherwise I would post a snapshot of what I'm seeing. Basically, my tabs are just appearing as a group of tab names without any border to signify which tab is currently active.

Comment: code would be nice. we can't help you if we don't know what isn't working for ya.

Comment: Is **bootstrap.css** loading properly?

Comment: What "Bootstrap tutorial example"? Are you referring to the [official docs](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs)?